# How can I get ExtJS 4 to work in Rails 3.1?

Tags: extjs, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I copied the `ExtJS4` directory in the assets folder.  I then included it like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag     "application", "ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag  "application", "ext-4.0.2a/ext-all-debug" %>
```

I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::EncodingError in Welcome#index
/Users/cbmeeks/Dropbox/Projects/myapp/app/assets/javascripts/ext-4.0.2a/locale/ext-lang-en_GB.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
```

Any ideas?

Is there a better way to include ExtJS in `Rails 3.1`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid activating Sprockets and get the files straight from app's public folder, put the leading slash:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag     "application", "/ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag  "application", "/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all-debug" %>
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks.  So, HOW did that work?  How does simply including it from the public directory make it different than the asset pipeline?  Thanks